# How do I embed $M/(N \cap N')$ as a submodule of $(M/N) \oplus (M/N')$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I embed $M/(N \cap N')$ as a submodule of $(M/N) \oplus(M/N')$? My thought it the following...

Simply send $m + N \cap N'$ to $(m + N, m + N').$ There is no ambiguity as $N \cap N'$ is a submodule of both $N$ and $N'.$ It is also injective by obvious reasons. Is this the correct way of looking at this?

Comment: $m + N \cap N' = m' + N \cap N' \implies m - m' \in N \cap N' \subset N, N'$ so $m + N = m' + N$ sim. $N'$.  So yes, the subset causes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Alternatively and more explicitly, you could just note that the natural map

$f:m\mapsto (m+N, m+N')$ is a homomorphism, and by the first homomorphism theorem $M/\ker(f)\cong Im(f)$, but $\ker(f)=N\cap N'$. So the image of $f$ in $(M/N)\times (M/N')$ is isomorphic to $M/(N\cap N')$.

Comment: That's actually really cool. Thanks!